# How to fix the output?

Tags: symfony

I need of you for helping to resolve my problem.
I use Symfony 4 for display some charts with the bundle google charts

Thanks you a lot

This is my function controller

```
 /**
 * @Route("/admin/test", name="statsTest")
 */
public function statsTest(){
    $results = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(IssueNubitalk::class)
        ->CountIssueByPartenaire('Canal');

    dump($results);

//        $results = [];
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
//            dump($results);
        $results[] = [
            'campaign' => $val->getCampaign(),
            'total' => $val->getTotal(),
        ];
    }
    dump($results);

    $data = json_decode(json_encode($results), true);
    $pieChart = new PieChart();
    $pieChart->getData()->setArrayToDataTable($data);
    $pieChart->getOptions()->setHeight(250);
    $pieChart->getOptions()->setWidth(400);
    $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setBold(true);
    $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setColor('#009900');
    $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setItalic(true);
    $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setFontName('Arial');
    $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setFontSize(20);
    return $this->render('backend/test.html.twig', [
        'piechart' => $pieChart,
    ]);
}
```

this is my repository

```
    public function CountIssueByPartenaire($partenaire){

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('i.campaign')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT i.sessionId) as total')
        ->where('i.campaign LIKE :campaign')
        ->setParameter('campaign', $partenaire.'_%')
        ->groupBy('i.campaign')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

this is the output

```
Call to a member function getCampaign() on array
```

Comment: use getResult() not getArrayResult(), it should return you doctrine2 entities instead of their array representation.

Comment: `$val['Campaign']` instead? But as stated Pierre, you'd rather use `getResult()` in your repository

Comment: Yes, I already used getResult() but same error.

Comment: clear the cache

Comment: foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
//            dump($results);
            $results = [
                ['Canal', 'Nombre d\'appel'],
                [$val['campaign'],
                $val['total']]
//                'campaign' => $val->getCampaign(),
//                'total' => $val->getTotal(),
            ];
        }

I want it like 
        $data =  [
            ['Canal', 'Nombre d\'appel'],
            ['Video', 626],
            ['Tchat', 1013]
        ];

Comment: Did you try to dump `$val` in your foreach ? if yes, what's the output ? your expected results (but in array form) ?
pretty weird the `getResult()` methd return you an array for `$val`.

Comment: output $val in my foreach
array:2 [▼
  "campaign" => "Canal_chat"
  "total" => "1013"
]
array:2 [▼
  "campaign" => "Canal_video"
  "total" => "628"
]

Comment: plse, i need of you.